# How to stop infinite loop in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, executiontimeout

If my code has infinite loop or Thread.Sleep(999999999), executionTimeout and AsyncTimeout value(10s) has no effect.
So, how to stop infinite loop in asp.net mvc, throw timeout exception and request is finish?

Comment: why would your code have an infinite loop ? isn't better to add some validation to prevent it in the first place?

Comment: start a timer quick before execution of for loop. Check timer value in each iteration and set timeout to true after the time you need to stop